# Failing to compile a c++ application under MacOS Catalina 10.15

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, macos-catalina

**Note:** For how I solved the problem, please look at the end of the post.

Yesterday, I have updated to MacOS Catalina 10.15 and since then I am trying to compile [this](https://github.com/harrytodorov/nori) c++ application (a fork of the [nori](https://github.com/wjakob/nori) educational ray tracer), but for some reason CMake fails to find the **pthread** library. Here is the output after running CMake:

```sh
$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 11.0.0.11000033
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 11.0.0.11000033
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Setting build type to 'Release' as none was specified.
-- Performing Test HAS_CPP14_FLAG
-- Performing Test HAS_CPP14_FLAG - Success
-- Performing Test HAS_CPP11_FLAG
-- Performing Test HAS_CPP11_FLAG - Success
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/libz.dylib (found version "1.2.11")
-- Performing Test HAVE_GCC_INLINE_ASM_AVX
-- Performing Test HAVE_GCC_INLINE_ASM_AVX - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_SYSCONF_NPROCESSORS_ONLN
-- Performing Test HAVE_SYSCONF_NPROCESSORS_ONLN - Failed
-- TBB: NOT using libc++.
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - not found
CMake Error at /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find Threads (missing: Threads_FOUND)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindThreads.cmake:220 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  ext/nanogui/ext/glfw/CMakeLists.txt:60 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/harry/dev/nori/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/Users/harry/dev/nori/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

And following is the `CMakeError.log`:

```sh
Performing C++ SOURCE FILE Test HAVE_GCC_INLINE_ASM_AVX failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /Users/harry/dev/nori/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_1e411/fast && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_1e411.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_1e411.dir/build
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_1e411.dir/src.cxx.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++    -std=c++14 -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-switch -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-deprecated-register -DHAVE_GCC_INLINE_ASM_AVX -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/DriverKit19.0.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/DriverKit19.0.sdk   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_1e411.dir/src.cxx.o -c /Users/harry/dev/nori/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx
clang: error: invalid version number in '-mmacosx-version-min=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/DriverKit19.0.sdk'
clang: warning: using sysroot for 'DriverKit' but targeting 'MacOSX' [-Wincompatible-sysroot]
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_1e411.dir/src.cxx.o] Error 1
make: *** [cmTC_1e411/fast] Error 2


Source file was:

    int main()
    {
     #if defined(__GNUC__) && defined(__SSE2__)
         int n   = 0;
         int eax = 0;
         int edx = 0;
         __asm__(
             "xgetbv     ;"
             "vzeroupper  "
             : "=a"(eax), "=d"(edx) : "c"(n) : );
     #else
         #error No GCC style inline asm supported for AVX instructions
     #endif
    }

Performing C++ SOURCE FILE Test HAVE_SYSCONF_NPROCESSORS_ONLN failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /Users/harry/dev/nori/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_db06f/fast && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_db06f.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_db06f.dir/build
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_db06f.dir/src.cxx.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++    -std=c++14 -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-switch -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-deprecated-register -DHAVE_SYSCONF_NPROCESSORS_ONLN -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/DriverKit19.0.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/DriverKit19.0.sdk   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_db06f.dir/src.cxx.o -c /Users/harry/dev/nori/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx
clang: error: invalid version number in '-mmacosx-version-min=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/DriverKit19.0.sdk'
clang: warning: using sysroot for 'DriverKit' but targeting 'MacOSX' [-Wincompatible-sysroot]
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_db06f.dir/src.cxx.o] Error 1
make: *** [cmTC_db06f/fast] Error 2


Source file was:

    #include <unistd.h>
    int main()
    {
        sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
    }

Performing C++ SOURCE FILE Test HAS_LIBCPP failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /Users/harry/dev/nori/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_4098b/fast && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_4098b.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_4098b.dir/build
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_4098b.dir/src.cxx.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++    -std=c++14 -fvisibility=hidden -DHAS_LIBCPP -stdlib=libc++ -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/DriverKit19.0.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/DriverKit19.0.sdk   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_4098b.dir/src.cxx.o -c /Users/harry/dev/nori/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx
clang: error: invalid version number in '-mmacosx-version-min=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/DriverKit19.0.sdk'
clang: warning: using sysroot for 'DriverKit' but targeting 'MacOSX' [-Wincompatible-sysroot]
clang: error: invalid deployment target for -stdlib=libc++ (requires OS X 10.7 or later)
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_4098b.dir/src.cxx.o] Error 1
make: *** [cmTC_4098b/fast] Error 2


...and run output:

Return value: 1
Source file was:
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char **argv) { std::cout << "test"; return 0; }
Performing C++ SOURCE FILE Test SUPPORTS_STDCXX11 failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /Users/harry/dev/nori/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_74f47/fast && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_74f47.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_74f47.dir/build
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_74f47.dir/src.cxx.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++    -std=c++14 -fvisibility=hidden -DSUPPORTS_STDCXX11 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/DriverKit19.0.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/DriverKit19.0.sdk   -std=c++11 -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_74f47.dir/src.cxx.o -c /Users/harry/dev/nori/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx
clang: error: invalid version number in '-mmacosx-version-min=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/DriverKit19.0.sdk'
clang: warning: using sysroot for 'DriverKit' but targeting 'MacOSX' [-Wincompatible-sysroot]
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_74f47.dir/src.cxx.o] Error 1
make: *** [cmTC_74f47/fast] Error 2


Source file was:
int main() { return 0; }
Performing C++ SOURCE FILE Test SUPPORTS_MRTM failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /Users/harry/dev/nori/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_60b35/fast && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_60b35.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_60b35.dir/build
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_60b35.dir/src.cxx.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++    -std=c++14 -fvisibility=hidden -DSUPPORTS_MRTM -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/DriverKit19.0.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/DriverKit19.0.sdk   -mrtm -Werror -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_60b35.dir/src.cxx.o -c /Users/harry/dev/nori/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx
clang: error: invalid version number in '-mmacosx-version-min=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/DriverKit19.0.sdk'
clang: error: using sysroot for 'DriverKit' but targeting 'MacOSX' [-Werror,-Wincompatible-sysroot]
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_60b35.dir/src.cxx.o] Error 1
make: *** [cmTC_60b35/fast] Error 2


Source file was:
int main() { return 0; }
Determining if the include file pthread.h exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /Users/harry/dev/nori/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_b4d5d/fast && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_b4d5d.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_b4d5d.dir/build
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_b4d5d.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc   -Wno-deprecated-declarations  -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/DriverKit19.0.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/DriverKit19.0.sdk   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_b4d5d.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o   -c /Users/harry/dev/nori/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c
clang: error: invalid version number in '-mmacosx-version-min=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/DriverKit19.0.sdk'
clang: warning: using sysroot for 'DriverKit' but targeting 'MacOSX' [-Wincompatible-sysroot]
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_b4d5d.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o] Error 1
make: *** [cmTC_b4d5d/fast] Error 2
```

The nori ray tracer expects XCode along with the command line tools installed on a MacOS machine. I have Xcode version 11.1 and the corresponding command line tools.

As far as I can see from the `CMakeError.log` file, clang produces an error, because of an invalid version number of **mmacosx-version-min**.

```sh
clang: error: invalid version number in '-mmacosx-version-min=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/DriverKit19.0.sdk'
```

I have researched a while trying to find clues on the topic, but failed to find something that solves my problem. The version of clang I have, is the one installed with Xcode: `Apple clang version 11.0.0`.

I am open to hear any suggestion and provide any additional information on my configuration you may find useful to pinpoint the issue.

---

*P.S.*: I forgot to mention, that back when I first started working on this project, I had a similar issue on MacOS Mojave [here](https://github.com/wjakob/nori/issues/16). And I was able to fix it by installing the SDK headers as noted in [this post](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/9050#issuecomment-424417456):

```sh
open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

***Working solution:*** Installing an older version of XCode (10.2.1 works well for me) and redirecting to it (making it the active developer directory with `xcode-select -s [path-to-old-xcode]`) turns out to solve my problem. The solution was proposed by Aaron19960821 from GitHub. See [here](https://github.com/wjakob/nori/issues/16).

Comment: Did you run `xcode-select --install` in the terminal after the update? That often fixes such problems.

Comment: Yes, I did run it. That was sadly one of my failed attempts to solve the problem

Comment: `TBB: NOT using libc++` suggests it is trying to use `libstdc++` which is no longer available with XCode

Comment: Oh, that is a good catch! Do you think, if I install an older version of Xcode (one which supports `libstdc++`) it may solve my issue? And is it even possible to install an older version of Xcode on MacOS Catalina?

Comment: It is hard to tell which of these submodules it causing the problem exactly, each of them is testing against the compiler flags and some of them are changing the compiler flags directly. That TBB and glfw don't compile might be caused by another submodule, because moving the `add_subdirectory` (and the corrsponding instructions around them) for `tbb` and `nanoui` to the top of `ext/CMakeLists.txt` makes those errors vanish, but it still fails.

Comment: You might have success to get it running if you compile each submodule in `ext` manually, and install it in e.g. `/opt/nori` and then change the CMakeFile of nori to link against those installed libraries.  Or maybe check if you could check if there is a newer version of those submodules available that resolves the problem.

Comment: Thanks! That's truly a good suggestion. I will try this probably the next days, as tomorrow I am meeting my professor to discuss the overall status of the project and still has to prepare some documents. 
I will update the topic, if your suggestion worked though. I am rather thinking of compiling each module in `ext` separately and linking them against nori.

Comment: Currently, I have deserted this approach and found it more convenient to use my corporate computer running Windows with WSL, as I have plenty of work to do on the project and this issue cost me more than a day...